# Shared executable memory

Tags: executable, virtual-memory, shared-memory, mmap

I have this short snippet of C:

```c
const char *name = "/asdf";
int desc = shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
ftruncate(desc, 4096);
void *block = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, desc, 0);
shm_unlink(name);
```

It creates a shared memory object, writable, readable, and execuable by everyone; and then maps it in memory with executable permissions. However, the `mmap` call fails with `EPERM` for some reason.
Strace gives the following:

```c
statfs("/dev/shm/", {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=450722, f_bfree=450372, f_bavail=450372, f_files=450722, f_ffree=450713, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
futex(0x7fa7f4c8b330, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/dev/shm/asdf", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0777) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
ftruncate(3, 4096)                      = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

The problem seems to arise from the use of `PROT_EXEC`, as `mmap` succeeds with any combination of permissions as long as there's no `PROT_EXEC`.
`mmap`ing without execute permissions and then trying to `mprotect` it fails as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're running Linux here, the `[no]exec`'ness of the `/dev/shm` mount gets propagated to the shared memory areas created by `shm_open` in current Linux kernels. So your issue will happen if your `/dev/shm` is mounted with the `noexec` mount option (which some distributions (Debian?) might do by default).

I've modified your code to add a `perror` (and return 2) in case of `mmap` failure:

```
testbox $ mount|grep shm
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
testbox $ ./a.out ; echo $?
0
testbox $ sudo mount -o remount,noexec /dev/shm
testbox $ mount|grep shm
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,noexec)
testbox $ ./a.out ; echo $?
mmap: Operation not permitted
2
```

Comment: Oh true, `shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`, would've never guessed it's the FS...

Comment: There's a long discussion here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/9/23/44 about this (starts with someone proposing a patch to essentially get rid of that behavior). I didn't read it all, but there's probably interesting info in there if you're curious.